# How can I calculate the sum in one of several growing groups in google sheets without manually adjusting all of the indexes?

Tags: google-sheets

I'll admit ahead of time, this'd probably be easier to do in multiple sheets, but because of my uses for this application, I'd prefer to combine each group into a single sheet.

Currently I have multiple grouped sections. Below each grouped second I have a row that exists to do a sum of the prior rows. On line E14 for example, I have the following cell.

=SUM(INDIRECT("E9:E"&row()-1))

This is all well and good for a single group, because continues to sum until the line before E14.

Then I have another group below E14 and another cell at E20 written as

=SUM(INDIRECT("E15:E"&row()-1))

The problem being that I could add row below E13. The query previously calculating from E9 to E13 will automatically sum until E14 like I want, but the second query will still try to sum from E15 to E20, even though the new starter row ought to be E16.

If it helps, I have been creating groups for each piece of my data, so there's a header row at E9 and grouped rows under it from E10-E13, a header at E15 and grouped rows under it from E16-E19, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: How groups are identified ? are they sorted ? Please share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: Put some sample data and output you want. That would be better for understanding your problem. It seems you can use `UNIQUE()` then `SUMIFS()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to use a named range in the formula. Specify a name for your Header cell and use it in the formula
*=SUM(OFFSET(Header1;1;1):OFFSET(B15;-1;0))*
or
*=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&ROW(Header1)+1&":B"&ROW()-1))*

[image]

[image]